# Acessing a database stand alone using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to obtain details about a schema and get the table objects using a stand alone active record connection. I am trying to do something like this

```
require'rubygems'
gem 'activerecord'
require 'activerecord'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => "mysql",
  :host     => "localhost",
  :username => "root",
  :database => "test_database"
)
```

Is it possible to access the tables of the db using this connection object.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? If you're not going to use ActiveRecord itself and just the DB connection, why bother using it at all and not just use the MySQL gem directly?

Comment: Andrew, I am currently using the mysql gem, Just wanted to know if there was any way using active record.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to use ActiveRecord without Rails.

You can also use standalone_migrations gem to manage ActiveRecord environment outside of Rails: https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to load all Active Support?

In order to have a near-zero default footprint, Active Support does not load anything by default. It is broken in small pieces so that you can load just what you need

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

[Active Support Core Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)